# NextJS Route Handlers and Prisma update recode issue

Tags: reactjs, database, next.js, jsx, prisma

i want to update the record in database for a single record using prisma and nextjs Route Handlers api

```
import prisma from "../../../../lib/prisma";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(req) {
  try {
    const { quantity, product_name } = req.json();

    const productUpdate = await prisma.products.update({
      where: {
        product_name: product_name,
      },
      data: {
        quantity: quantity,
      },
    });

    const data = JSON.stringify(productUpdate);
    return NextResponse.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    return NextResponse.error(
      "An error occurred while processing the request."
    );
  }
}
```

and when i send json content

```
{
  "quantity": 10,
  "product_name": "alfa Pen"
}
```

i got this error

```
Error: PrismaClientValidationError: 
Invalid `prisma.products.update()` invocation:

{
  where: {
    product_name: undefined,
?   id?: Int
  },
  data: {
    quantity: undefined
  }
}

Argument `where` of type ProductsWhereUniqueInput needs at least one argument. Available options are listed in green.
```

i also try to update multiple recorded

```
    import prisma from "../../../../lib/prisma";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(req) {
  try {
    const { quantity, product_name ,price } = req.json();

    const productUpdate = await prisma.products.updateMany({
      where: {product_name:{
        contains: product_name,
      }
      },
      data: {
        quantity: quantity,
        price: price,
      },
    });

    const data = JSON.stringify(productUpdate);
    return NextResponse.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    return NextResponse.error(
      "An error occurred while processing the request."
    );
  }
}
```

i got this

```
"{\"count\":0}"
```

and here is the prisma schema

```
generator client {
    provider        = "prisma-client-js"
    previewFeatures = ["jsonProtocol", "fullTextSearch", "fullTextIndex"]
}

datasource db {
    provider          = "postgresql"
    url               = env("POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL") // uses connection pooling
    directUrl         = env("POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING") // uses a direct connection
}

model Products {
    id                  Int             @id @unique @default(dbgenerated("floor(random() * (9999 - 1000 + 1)) + 1000"))
    product_name        String          @unique @db.VarChar(50)
    product_description String          @db.Text
    quantity            Int             @db.Integer
    price               Decimal         @db.Decimal()
    pproduct            Category        @relation(fields: [category_name], references: [category_name])
    category_name       String
    productsOrder_id    Int
    ProductsOrder       ProductsOrder[]
}

model Category {
    id            Int        @id @unique @default(dbgenerated("floor(random() * (9999 - 1000 + 1)) + 1000"))
    category_name String     @unique @db.VarChar(50)
    products      Products[]
}

model ProductsOrder {
    id          Int        @id @unique @default(dbgenerated("floor(random() * (9999 - 1000 + 1)) + 1000"))
    date        DateTime   @default(now())
    quantity    Int        @db.Integer
    totalAmount Decimal    @db.Decimal()
    products    Products[]
}

model Service {
    id           Int            @id @unique @default(dbgenerated("floor(random() * (9999 - 1000 + 1)) + 1000"))
    serviceName  String         @db.VarChar(50)
    price        Decimal        @db.Decimal()
    ServiceOrder ServiceOrder[]
}

model ServiceOrder {
    id          Int       @id @unique @default(dbgenerated("floor(random() * (9999 - 1000 + 1)) + 1000"))
    quantity    Int       @db.Integer
    totalAmount Decimal   @db.Decimal()
    services    Service[]
}
```

i also check for wrong variable or non existing rescored but nothing is missing or wrong variable in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the post works when add await after req.json

```
import prisma from "../../../../lib/prisma";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(req) {
  try {
    const { quantity, product_name, price } = await req.json();

    const productUpdate = await prisma.products.updateMany({
      where: { product_name:{contains:product_name} },
      data: {
        quantity: quantity,
        price: price,
      },
    });

    const data = JSON.stringify(productUpdate);
    return NextResponse.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    return NextResponse.error(
      "An error occurred while processing the request."
    );
  }
}
```